# Twilio agent conference outbound call recording

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I would like to get the recordings for outbound calls made by me, basically, we have a conference which the I join, and then use the outbound call api to add in the destination calls. See code below.

code to create conference

```js
const conference_props = {
    beep: true,
    startConferenceOnEnter: true,
    endConferenceOnExit: false,
    maxParticipants: 2,
    eventCallbackUrl: '/callback',
    record: 'record-from-start',
    recordingStatusCallback: '/callback',
    trim: true
};
const dial = twiml.dial();

dial.conference('conferencename', conference_props);
```

code to add the calls

```js
phone
.conferences('conferencename')
.participants.create({
  to: '+123455666',
  from: '+123455666',
  earlyMedia: true,
  record: true,
  trim: true,
  startConferenceOnEnter: true,
  endConferenceOnExit: true,
  conferenceStatusCallback: '/callback'
})
.then(participant => console.log(participant.sid), (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

however the only callbacks i get is at the end of the conference. This previously worked fine when using the old style conferences and dialling a call then adding it to the conference on connect, but i want to have the earlymedia (ringing noise) that the agent conference provides

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this, they way i did it was to modify the outbound call part, the url has to be absolute, so https://www.blah.com/callback and set on **statusCallback** not **conferenceStatusCallback**

so

```js
phone
.conferences('conferencename')
.participants.create({
  to: '+123455666',
  from: '+123455666',
  earlyMedia: true,
  record: true,
  trim: true,
  startConferenceOnEnter: true,
  endConferenceOnExit: true,
  statusCallback: 'https://www.example.com/callback'
})
.then(participant => console.log(participant.sid), (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```